# Getting GraphQL working with Authorization header

Tags: htaccess, graphql

[In the docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/graphql.html#querying-a-private-schema), the following is written:

> Apache strips Authorization headers by default, which can be fixed by enabling CGIPassAuth or adding the following to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

It seems like, that I'm facing this problem. When I add those two lines in my .htaccess file inside the web folder, nothing changes. I still get this response:

```
{
    "name": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Missing Authorization header",
    "code": 0,
    "status": 400,
    "type": "yii\\web\\BadRequestHttpException"
}
```

This is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Do I need to put a .htaccess file with the two lines somewhere else for this to work?
I have set up the route for GraphQL as described in the docs: `'api' => 'graphql/api'`

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution @obs?
I have, in contrast to your problem, the message "Invalid Authorization header".

I also added the rewrite stuff in my /web/.htaccess file, but no effect... :S

Comment: Hm maybe it is because my whole .htacess has no effect at all. I am using ddev and I think per default it is using nginx and not apache...